# Argument error in model scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I'm trying to refactor the Companies_Controller#index method to encompass less logic by moving most of the query into a scope, `company_search_params`.

What is the best way to pass the param to the model scope? I'm getting an error thrown back, *wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)*. I'm relatively new to writing scopes and couldn't find much on passing arguments/conditions that was applicable in the Rails Guide.

***Companies Controller***

```
 def index
    params[:name_contains] ||= ''
    Company.company_search_params(params[:name_contains])

    @search = Company.company_search_params
    @companies = @search.page(params[:page])
  end
```

***Company Model***

```
scope :company_search_params, ->(name_contains){
    where(
    <<-SQL
      "name LIKE :match OR subdomain LIKE :match", { match: "%#{name_contains}%" }
    SQL
    ).where(is_archived: false).order(name: :asc)
  }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you have both `Company.company_search_params(params[:name_contains])` and `@search = Company.company_search_params`? The first does nothing because you're paying attention to the return value, the second is causing your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using named_scope sample and info

```
scope :named_scope, lambda {
  |variable1, variable2|
  where...
  order...
}

#when you call it from your controller

Model.named_scope("value 1","value 2")
```

for your problem

in your company.rb

```
scope :company_search_params, lambda { 
  |name_contains|
  where(
  <<-SQL
    "name LIKE :match OR subdomain LIKE :match", { match: "%#{name_contains}%" }
  SQL
  ).where(is_archived: false).order(name: :asc)
}
```

company_controller.rb

```
def index
  @search = Company.company_search_params(params[:name_contains])
  @companies = @search.page(params[:page])
end
```